# Como puedo hacer que un boton sea resposivo

Tags: html5

Como puedo hacer que un boton se adapte al tamaño de la pagina, estoy realizando una pagina y no puedo hacer que el boton se adabte al tamaño cuando la pagina se haga mas chica.

Small button
https://tecmmstore.myshopify.com/

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible y especifica en tu pregunta cómo quieres que se comporte el botón...¿debe ocupar toda la pantalla, hacerse más pequeño...?

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que puedes hacerlo proporcionalmente, es decir darle un width porcentual y el debe adaptarse a partir de la resolución. Otra es a partir de media querys controlar las resoluciones y darle el width que desees.

En el HTML

```
<button class="btn">Prueba</button>
```

En el CSS

```
.btn{
  width: 10%;
}
```